# rss feed pulls in featured posts but need limited description

Tags: php, css, wordpress, rss

I figured out how to limit my post words. The problem I am having is that my css code almost centers the 3 posts but it still favors the left side a little. These will not be the colors that I will be using they are just helping me with layout. If anyone could help in anyway it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the php code

```
<section id="blog">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div id="blog_title">

            Featured Posts

        </div><!--END BLOG TITLE-->

<div id="featured_posts">

<?php

// output RSS feed to HTML
output_rss_feed('http://www.bmcsquincy.com/featured_posts/feed', 20, true, true, 200);

// Check http://www.systutorials.com/136102/a-php-function-for-fetching-rss-feed-and-outputing-feed-items-as-html/ for description
// RSS to HTML
/*
    $item_cnt: max number of feed items to be displayed
    $max_words: max number of words (not real words, HTML words)
    if <= 0: no limitation, if > 0 display at most $max_words words
 */
function get_rss_feed_as_html($feed_url, $max_item_cnt = 10, $show_date = true, $show_description = true, $max_words = 0, $cache_timeout = 7200, $cache_prefix = "/tmp/rss2html-")
{
    $result = "";
    // get feeds and parse items
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $cache_file = $cache_prefix . md5($feed_url);
    // load from file or load content
    if ($cache_timeout > 0 &&
        is_file($cache_file) &&
        (filemtime($cache_file) + $cache_timeout > time())) {
            $rss->load($cache_file);
    } else {
        $rss->load($feed_url);
        if ($cache_timeout > 0) {
            $rss->save($cache_file);
        }
    }
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array (
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
        $content = $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded'); // <content:encoded>
        if ($content->length > 0) {
            $item['content'] = $content->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    // real good count
    if ($max_item_cnt > count($feed)) {
        $max_item_cnt = count($feed);
    }
    $result .= '<ul class="feed-lists">';


    //ADDED THIS FOR POST AMOUNT
    $max_item_cnt = 3;
    $max_words = 25;

    for ($x=0;$x<$max_item_cnt;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $result .= '<li class="feed-item">';
        $result .= '<div class="feed-title"><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong></div>';
        if ($show_date) {
            $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            $result .= '<small class="feed-date"><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small>';
        }
        if ($show_description) {
            $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
            $content = $feed[$x]['content'];
            // find the img
            $has_image = preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $image);
            // no html tags
            $description = strip_tags($description, '');
            // whether cut by number of words
            if ($max_words > 0) {
                $arr = explode(' ', $description);
                if ($max_words < count($arr)) {
                    $description = '';
                    $w_cnt = 0;
                    foreach($arr as $w) {
                        $description .= $w . ' ';
                        $w_cnt = $w_cnt + 1;
                        if ($w_cnt == $max_words) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $description .= " ...";
                }
            }
            // add img if it exists

            //ADDED THE P IN DESCRIPTION LINE TO FOR A BREAK BY IMAGE

            if ($has_image == 1) {
                $description = '<p> <a href="'.$link.'" img="'.$description.'"> <img class="feed-item-image" src="' . $image['src'] . '" /></a></p>' . $description;
            }
            $result .= '<div class="feed-description">' . $description;

            //ADDED THE P IN THIS TO LINE BREAK CONTINUE READING

            $result .= '<p> <a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">Continue Reading &raquo;</a></p>'.'</div>';
        }
        $result .= '</li>';
    }
    $result .= '</ul>';
    return $result;
}
function output_rss_feed($feed_url, $max_item_cnt = 10, $show_date = true, $show_description = true, $max_words = 0)
{
    echo get_rss_feed_as_html($feed_url, $max_item_cnt, $show_date, $show_description, $max_words);
}
?>

</div><!--END FEATURED POSTS-->

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="blog_btn_section"> 
             <div id="btn_see_work" class="col-md-12 text-center"><a class="button btn btn-default btn-md wp5 delay-3s" id="btn-intro" href="./contact.php" target="_top">SEE MORE
            </a>
            </div><!--END BUTTON-->
        </div><!--END COL SPAN-->

    </div><!--END ROW-->
    </div><!--END CONTAINER-->
</section><!--END SECTION BLOG-->
```

Here is my CSS that is giving me alignment troubles

```
#blog {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #dbdbdb;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

#blog_title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: pathwaygothic;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: green;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#blog_btn_section {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#featured_posts {
    background-color: pink;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

#featured_posts ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

#featured_posts li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 30px;
    float: left;
    font-family: pathwaygothic;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: purple;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.feed-lists {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;

}

.feed-title a {
    color: red;
}

.feed-date {
    color: aqua;
}

.feed-description {
    width: 300px;
}

.feed-lists li {
    background-color: green;
}

.feed-item-image:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #333333;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: When you say: `need limited description`, do you mean the _length_ of the `<description>` tag? this tag brings HTML code, so you have to override the HTML code for get the text only. Please clarify which would be the desired result that you want get,

Comment: Mauricio, Sorry for the confusion! I figured out what I needed. I added a $max_words = 25; in the php code and it seemed to work! But I have been struggling to figure out why my css is not aligning in the center for the actual posts. They are off just slightly.

Comment: Digital_Jedi_3; I'm glad you figured out about `$max_words = 25;` and about css, well, I can't help you in this point, but, if you can edit your question with the styles applied to a sample HTML code (using code snippet), maybe another user with more knowledge can help you. Cheers.

Comment: thank you much appreciated!